# Using regasm with AnyCPU DLL for both 32 bit and 64 bit using Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup, regasm, anycpu

I have a C# COM DLL that has been compiled with the setting **Any CPU**.

At the moment I have put this into the script:

```
[Run]
Filename: "{dotnet40}\regasm.exe"; Parameters: "MSAToolsGMailClassLibrary.dll /codebase"; WorkingDir: "{app}"; Flags: runhidden
Filename: "{dotnet4064}\regasm.exe"; Parameters: "MSAToolsGMailClassLibrary.dll /codebase"; WorkingDir: "{app}"; Flags: runhidden; Check: IsWin64

[UninstallRun]
Filename: {dotnet40}\regasm.exe; Parameters: /u MSAToolsGMailClassLibrary.dll; WorkingDir: {app}; Flags: runhidden
Filename: {dotnet4064}\regasm.exe; Parameters: /u MSAToolsGMailClassLibrary.dll; WorkingDir: {app}; Flags: runhidden; Check: IsWin64;
```

Since there is only one file (but my installer installs my application in both 32 bit and 64 bit) have I done the right thing here by putting it twice?

Comment: I believe your script is correct. Do you have any reason for your doubts?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl That is good to know. Just wasn’t sure. Thanks.